# Create all combination of 11 names out of 22 where sum of credit is 100

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I have two columns one has 22 Names and another column with respective credit against each name. I need to know all the combination of 11 names which sums up to 100.

[i am attaching image of data for example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBWuW.png)

I searched and returned with `itertool` which gets you all the combination. But I was not sure of how this can be used to get all the combination.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import permutations
data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\anup.kumar.dutta\Documents\Test\Test.xlsx',index=False)
def f(length,total_sum):
    if length == 1:
        yield (total_sum,)
    else:
        for value in range(total_sum + 1):
            for permutation in sum(length - 1,total_sum - value):
                yield (value,) + permutation

L = list(f(5,100))
print('total permutations:',len(L))
```

It should return all combination of names which sums up to credit 100.

Comment: [Don't post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) of your data, we cannot copy and paste it to answer your question. Try to add a small example dataframe which represents your actual data. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) thread on how to make a good pandas question in specific

Answer (score 1):

Doing combinations calculations of this sort is not quick. I'm timing it using time.time.

```
starttime = time.time()
```

We will use combintations from itertools.

```
from itertools import combinations
```

First I will recreate your data (please include next time for responders so we don't have to recreate). I'm using letters for names. I will use pd.Series as this fits your data and this will be quickest next to using numpy directly.

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(8,11,22), index = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV'))
```

Next set the combination parameters.

```
# set combination parameters
r =  11
n = len(s)
```

Create a list for tracking the names whose scores == 100.

```
name_list = []
```

Finally, loop through the combinations storing all combinations summing to 100.

```
for p in combinations(s.index, r):
    if s.loc[list(p)].sum() == 100:
        name_list.append(p)

endtime = time.time()



print('Time to run', endtime - starttime)
Time to run 350.4899344444275

name_list (fist ten rows)

[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'M'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'T'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'V'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'M', 'T'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'M', 'V'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'T', 'V'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'M'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'T'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'V'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'M', 'O'),...
```

How many combinations are there?

```
print(len(name_list))
86724
```